# Did Ramayana occur 1.6 million years ago?

Tags: ramayana

Many Western scholars and Indian scholars with Western mindset tried to fix the age of Srimad Ramayana, to approximately the 5th to 4th century BC.   And, they succeeded to some extent in making people believe in the above fictitious theory.

If we study Srimad Ramayana in depth, we will get a clue to this riddle.

---

After conquering Lankhini, the Godess of Lanka, Sri Hanuma enters Lanka and searches for Seeta. Sage Valmiki describes what Sri Hanuma saw, as follows:

> त्रिविष्टप निभम् दिव्यम् दिव्य नाद विनादितम् |
>   वाजि हेषित सम्घुष्टम् नादितम् भूषणैः तथा || 
>   रथैः यानैः विमानैः च तथा गज हयैः शुभैः |
>   वारणैः च चतुः दन्तैः श्वेत अभ्र निचय उपमैः ||
>  
>   भूषितम् रुचिर द्वारम् मत्तैः च मृग पक्षिभिः |
>   राक्षस अधिपतेः गुप्तम् आविवेश गृहम् कपिः ||
>
> The great Hanuma entered secretly Ravana's inner city which was equal to paradise, rendered noisy by neighing of horses and tinkling of ornaments, by chariots, vehicles and aerial-cars and decorated by auspicious elephants and horses and great elephants with four tusks and by birds and animals in heat. It had beautiful entrances and was protected by thousands of rakshasas with great strength.

(Sundara Kanda 4th Sarga 26 - 28 Slokas)

> उत्तमम् राक्षसावासम् हनुमानवलोकयन् |
>   आससादाथ लक्ष्मीवान् राक्षसेन्द्रनिवेशनम् || 
>   चतुर् विषाणैर् द्विरदैः त्रिविषाणैः तथैव च |
>   परिक्षिप्तम् असम्बाधम् रक्ष्यमाणम् उदायुधैः ||
>
> Thereafter, Hanuma the glorious one neared and observed the best residence of Rakshasas and the house of Ravana, containing elephants with four tusks and also those with three tusks, those with two tusks and still not crowded. It was protected by soldiers bearing raised weapons.

(Sundara Kanda 9th Sarga 4 - 5 Slokas)

Here, Sage Valmiki describes **elephants with four tusks** and also those with three tusks and those with two tusks.

### Modern  anthropologists say that elephants with four tusks existed 12-1.6 million years ago.

The Gomphotheriidae were a diverse taxonomic family of extinct elephant-like animals (proboscideans). Referred to as gomphotheres, they were widespread in North America during the Miocene and Pliocene epochs, 12-1.6 million years ago. Some lived in parts of Eurasia, Beringia and, following the Great American Interchange, South America.

Gomphotheres differed from elephants in their tooth structure, particularly the chewing surfaces on the molar teeth. Most had four tusks, and their retracted facial and nasal bones prompt palaeontologists to believe that gomphotheres had elephant-like trunks.

---

Hence, can we infer that Srimad Ramayana occurred  16 lakh or 1.6 million years ago and not 5th to 4th century BC, as the scholars made us believe?

Comment: I think those four-tucked elephants were plundered from Devaloka, they're not elephants that were naturally occurring at the time on Earth.  In any case, I certainly agree that the Western Indologists are completely off in their dating.

Comment: Well if we were to take the Yuga calculations in the puranas, it is said Ramayana occurred in the 24th Treta Yuga, and we are now in 28th Kali Yuga. This would mean that Ramayana happened more than 17 million years ago or 1.7 crore years ago. However if we were to go by just the dating of the elephants, one can argue that those elephants were taken from Devaloka (like Keshav said) looong after they had become extinct on Earth.

Comment: Also I am a little skeptical of the radiometric dating methods, because I have read in places that the archaologists (or whoever is doing it) continuously reject those dates that do not fit with their 'idea' of when the fossil should have existed, and only take those dates which match their 'scientific' view of the timeline of the Earth :) all the best

Comment: Related question for others to see: [ISR finds birthdate of Lord Rama 10th January 5114 BC. What about Kalki avatar?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/8663/1049)

Comment: Ram setu was 1.7 milon years old [click here](http://www.rense.com/general30/nasa.htm)

Comment: Lord Rama came in 24 manvantara. Lord Krishna in 28th. So - Ramayana 20 millions year old!

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan Sir, what do you think are correct dates of Ramayana and Mahabharata? Like how many years ago did Ram and Krishna lived? Some say Ramayana happened 5000 years ago, while some say it happened around 1.6 million years ago. What do you think is correct?

Comment: In this case, you need not blame moderators.  It was done by a group of 5 members, who thought it to be closed.  If you are feeling it to be reopened, click on reopen button, below the question @Lokesh

Comment: There is unfortenately no proof of the Ramayana. It remains a hypothesis until this day.

Comment: Now its 28 yuga cycle ramayana happened 19h treta yuga..because parasurama avatara also happened in 19th treta yuga..

Answer (score 8):

Yes Ramayana was written approx 1.6 million years ago.

**I have another proof from Ramayana.**

Earth is believed to have land as Pangaea (pan-jee-ə), which was a supercontinent  that existed during the late Paleozoic and early Mesozoic eras, forming approximately 300 million years ago.

The oldest epic sanskrit poem, Ramayana, composed by sage Valmiki,
gives clues about this single large continent that existed approximately 200,100,000 years ago.

The single global ocean which surrounded Pangaea is accordingly named Panthalassa.
Pangea must have been drowned into Panthalassa by Hiranyaksha and was later restored by Varaha – third incarnation of Vishnu as a wild boar
and that is when present aeon/creation of Sveta Varaha Kalpa started. (according to Vishnu Purana and Bhagavata Purana)

The legend of King Sagara provides many vital clues that signify an intimate knowledge of the ancient world’s
geography including Pangea Supercontinet Map.

The episode detailing the story of King Sagara represents a time going back approximately 200,100,000 years ago.
As the Ramayana records at that time there was only One Landmass Surrounded by One Ocean.

King Sagara said to his sons :

> tat gacchata vicinvadhvam putrakaa bhadram astu
>
> vah samudra maaliniim
> sarvaam prithiviim anugacchata  [Ramayana : 1-39-13]

**Oh, sons, you may therefore proceed to search for the horse and its thief on this Entire Earth which is Garlanded by the Ocean.
Safety upon you all. [Ramayana : 1-39-13]**

You can get more description from [**here**](http://hinduismdecoded.blogspot.in/2015/03/pangea-supercontinet-od-ancient-earth.html)

Comment: Humans didnt exist millions of years ago!

Comment: If all the land on Earth was a single island (super-continent) during the period of Ramayana, why would Hanuma need to fly over the waters to reach Lanka? They could have just walked, on land, without Rama Sethu.

Comment: @AdityaK: human existed 2.8 million years ago even more earlier than that see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_human_evolution_fossils#Late_Miocene

Comment: @sv. King Sagara: 200,100,000 years before Ramayana; & 
Lord Ram : 1,700,000 years before now

Answer (score 6):

Ramayana was not written 1.6 million years ago because Lord Rama was born in Treta Yuga and Treta Yuga consists of 3600 years.

Manu Samhita clearly describes the length of the yuga but certain scholars have miscalculated the length of the Yugas.

The Yuga length has been clearly described in "The Holy Science" by Sri Yukteswar Giri. According to it, Satya Yuga consists of 4800 years, Treta Yuga consits of 3600 years, Dwapara Yuga consists of 2400 years and Kali Yuga consists of 1200 years. Sri Yukteswar also mentions that we are living in ascending Dwapara Yuga rather than Kali Yuga which most people believe. Ascending Kali Yuga ended in 1699. The next age will be ascending Treta Yuga. Lord Rama was born in descending Treta Yuga.

[image]

In Sundara Kandam([Sarga 34](http://www.valmikiramayan.net/sundara/sarga34/sundara_34_frame.htm)), Sita says:

> kalyaaNii bata gathaa iyam laukikii pratibhaati me |
>
> ehi jiivantam aanado naram varSha shataat api ||

It means "Joy rushes to surviving man even though (it be) as the end of a hundred years - this popular adage appears true and and auspicious for me."

It is clear that the average life span of a person was 100 years and not in 1000s. Now because it is written that Lord Rama ruled for 10000 years, this figure must be inflated. The wrong calculation was arrived after yuga years have been multiplied by 360. If you multiply 360 with any of the above yuga figure, you will get the inflated figures mentioned in some of the scriptures. The same can be said of Lord Rama years ruled. To get the correct figure, we divide 10000 by 360 and get a figure of 27-28 years which makes sense considering 100 years was the average life span.

So if we calculate from the present time(2015), 5115 years have passed since the end of descending Treta Yuga. Now because Treta Yuga consists of 3600 years so we can add to it the years already passed since Treta Yuga's end i.e 3600 + 5115 = 8715 years. It means descending Treta Yuga started 8715 years ago and ended 5115 years ago. **Lord Rama was born in this period** and Ramayan was written thereafter.

*The above image was taken from [wolindia.com](http://www.wolindia.com/2012/01/swami-sri-yukteswar-giri-explains-yuga.html).*

Comment: I do not know the basis of the above explanation.  There are 2 issues need clarification from your side. (1) There was no mention about Yuda division in Srimad Ramayana.  Then how can you restrict the span of Treta Yuga to 3,600 years?  (2) In the Last Sarga of Srimad Ramayana it was mentioned that Sri Rama ruled for 10,000 years.  How do you account for it, if we restrict the span of Treta Yuga to 3,600 years?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I have added some details regarding life span in Treta Yuga.

Comment: So according to you everything mentioned in Srimad Ramayana has to be divided by 360?  when Sri Rama reached Chitrakuta, his age was mentioned as 25 years. Does it mean, his age should be 25/360 = 0.069 years?  That means he was not even a toddler.  Great concept of yours

Comment: By the way, can you explain where did you get this conversion factor of 360?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv You can read everything in "The Holy Science" by Sri Yukteswar. In that book everything is mentioned, the correct yuga length, how the wrong length has been ascertained and under what circumstances such things occured.

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Even Manu Samhita mentions the same yuga cycle as in "The Holy Science".

Comment: @srimannarayanakv According to the wrong calculations, 1 deva year is 360 human years which is wrong. I have got all this information from this book. And if you don't want to read the book, you can google about it.

Comment: Please answer my question with regard to Sri Rama's age at Chitrakuta

Comment: :When we are proposing something, it should cover all issues.  If your theory divides the ruling period of Sri Rama by 360, then it should divide every other age, ruling period. Doesn't it make sense?

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I feel this answer is more accurate and I too believe what Yukteswar has told about Yugas. Just imagine if Rama had lived 10k years then the 14 years *Vanvaas* would have looked as just 0.14% of his life. Will Kaikai give such a small duration if the life expectancy was too high or Dasaratha would have died so easily? You don't have to blindly divide everything by 360. From your (too many) comments, it seems that "seeking" part is missing. BTW I have completely ignored the argument that according to current science, modern human evolved just 100k years back.

Comment: @iammilind: When one type of conversion factor has to be used for deriving some answer, similar factor has to be used in similar situation. If we apply 360 conversion factor in the case of period of ruling of Sri Rama, we should apply to his age when he reached Chitrakuta,i.e, 25 years and conclude that he is not even toddler at that time.

Comment: @iammilind:  As I am seeker, I posted this question here for getting poised answers, but not quotations made from somebody's statements.  I am not questioning the knowledge of Sri Yukteswara giri.  I wanted a poised answer

Comment: @srimannarayanakv Since already too many comments on this thread, I will refrain from posting more for future users. The 360 or any X multiplier figure will make the yuga span too high if not used correctly. The numbers like 14 years in forest, 25 age Chitrakuta etc are indeed genuine figures. But some ignorants in between inflated other figures to thousands of years to make them superlative. Mahabharata being well documented in multiple sources, such adulteration was not possible. Rama's life span should be no different then today's human, except few more years(25-50) and healthier..

Comment: @srimannarayanakv I agree with iammilind that 14 years, the age of 25 at Chitrakuta are correct. I am not questioning everything written in Ramayan or any other scripture. I am not saying you have to multiply or divide every figure in the scriptures by 360. I am only against a few inflated figures.

Comment: It is left to your discretion please.  Everyone has liberty to have his own views.

Comment: @iammilind   If you do not accept long life of people in past then how do you adjust  surviving of Jambavan from Vaman to Ram to Krishna , Parashuram from Kartaveerya to Ramayan to Mahabharat to Kalki, Ravan fighting 27th Ikshvaku king Anaranya, Muchukundas sleeping in caves,  Dvida and other vanars from Ramayan to Krishna time, Jatayu from Samudra manthan to Ramayan, Ikshvaku king Maru coming in recent Satya, Ashwatthama becoming Saptarishi and Bali being Indra in Sarvani Manwantara..etc. so many other things...

Comment: @Chinmay SarupriaThese large ages are only when seen from earth 4320000 (1 chaturyuga) is just 12000 yrs. For Devaloka and 43.2 seconds for Brahmaloka.... From Brahmaloka 1 Lakh earth year passes each second.. Thus 10000 yrs of Ramrajya was less than a second from Brahmaloka....

Comment: @TejasweePokhrel My answer is against those figures only. The thing is, there is no such 'deva' years. On earth itself, there is just 12000 years that make half cycle.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria if Kali Yuga consists of 1200 human years and not Divine years then, is it already finished and we r in Satyuga as it started 5000+ years back???

Comment: @YDS No because descending Kali Yuga started in 701 BC, ended in 499 AD; ascending Kali Yuga started and ended in 1699 AD. We are in ascending Dwapara Yuga.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria Mahabharata says : "after the Kali Yuga is over, the Krita Yuga comes again" - http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03187.htm then how can u say that we are in ascending Dwapara Yuga?

Comment: @YDS The same page says "The next Yuga, called Kali, is said to comprise one thousand years and its dawn, as well as eve, is said to comprise one hundred years. A cycle of the Yugas thus comprised a period of twelve thousand years" This is the basis of Sri Yukteswar theory, Vedas say the same thing, Yajur Veda says the lifespan of humans is 100 years.

Comment: @ChinmaySarupria for a moment let's not talk about anything else here, and let's assume that as per ur theory it's normal human years and not celestial years...and u r saying that we r in Dwapara Yuga now...my only point is how Dwapara can came after Kaliyuga when scriptures say that Satayuga to come..or is there any other scripture which says that Dwapara also can come??..then there might be Kalpa-bheda and still Mahabharata seems right as it tells story from current Kalpa/Manavantra/YugaCycle..

Comment: @YDS I am not aware of any scripture that says Dwapara comes after Kali but I find Sri Yukteswar's reasons strong enough to believe. You can read it in "The Holy Science".

Comment: When was ascending Kali Yuga started according to him?

Comment: @YDS check out https://www.bibhudevmisra.com/2012/07/end-of-kali-yuga-in-2025-unraveling.html

Answer (score 4):

Chaturyuga is of 43,20,000 years,

In which krita yuga is of 432000*4=17,28,000 years

Thretha yuga is of 432000*3 = 12,96,000 years.
Dwapara yuga is of 432000*2 =8,64,000 years.
Kaliyuga is of 432000*1=432000 years.
Total 4yugas = 43,20,000 years

Here is the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yuga#Durations_of_the_four_Yugas) article for duration of Yuga's

Presently we are in Kaliyuga.. and have crossed 5120 years of [Kaliyuga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kali_Yuga#Current_Kali_Yuga_and_possible_starting_dates).

Rama was from [Treta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rama#Dating) yuga, so it's more than appx. 8,69,000 years ago.

Comment: you are taking the end of Dwapara yuga. But there no evidence from the Ramayana which tells us they were near the end of the yuga.

Answer (score 2):

There might be some people who have more scientific approach than mythological/vedic approach for them recently NASA did confirm about the age of Rama Setu and from that we can certainly conclude that Ramayana indeed happened some 1.6 million years ago.

Check it [out](https://krishna.org/nasa-images-discover-ancient-bridge-between-india-and-sri-lanka/). There are too many news articles published around last week or so confirming this fact.

Answer (score 2):

A Mahayuga comprises of 4 yugas of varying lengths of which Treta Yuga is the secons.  As per Srimad Baghavatam each Kalpa comrises of 14 Manvantaras. Each Manvantara is ruled by a different Manu who rules for 71 and 6.25 Mahayugas. Currently we are in Shwetavaraha Kalpa under Vaivaswata Manu.  We are living in the 28th Kali Yuga i.e in the 28th Mahayuga of Vaivaswata Manvantara. Each Mahayuga comprises 43,20,000 years.

Various Upa-Puranas list the war between Sri Rama and Raavana in the 24th Treta Yuga, i.e about 16 to 17 million years ago and not 1.6 million years. Therefore Ramayana is definitely more ancient than either dates given by Western Indologists, more likely 17 million years rather than 1.7 million years as some answers state.

Further, the dating given by Ashok Bhatnagar IRS used a software that could go back about 99,000 years. The cycle of 360 degrees of Astronomical signs is repeated 25000 plus years and so it may be possible that the astronomical details given in Ramayana could be repeated ad infinitum - accepting the geological age of the Earth as four billion years. And hence there is a high possibility that Ramayana occurred 16 / 17 million years ago.

Comment: That is not possbile since humans were not around around that time so either the book is work of fiction or the writer, possibly Valkimi, made a mistake.

Comment: @Wikash_ it cannot be a work of fiction. Because even Avesta Iranian religion tells us about the Lord Ram.

Comment: @Kumar There is no proof that humans were around that time. Please explain that. Also, that book was written at a time that humans were present so that does not backup your claim.

Comment: @Wikash_ I am not talking about the time. I am talking about the story. I don't mind the time they want to pick. But the story as a general is certainly true. Also about the science, it is not fixed as you think. We don't know about many things. We should not think inside of the box only. I mean, we don't have every answer to human civilization and genetics.

Comment: @Wikash_ a few years back on TV, I have seen a few people were making that comment on four or two trunk elephant (they are telling it cannot possible). But we know now it is certainly true. I am more positive and believe one day we might have all the answer we need using the science of course.

Comment: @Kumar yes we do not know everything and the time to believe something is when evidence is presented.

Answer (score -4):

In the Ayodhya Kaanda of Valmiki Ramayana, a Buddhist was compared to a thief and the Tathagatas to atheists (Naastiks). It said:

यथा हि चोर स्स तथा हि बुद्ध-
स्तथागतं नास्तिकमत्र विद्धि।

As a thief, so is Buddha. Know that Tathagatas are atheists. 
[Sarga 109; shloka 34].

Since "Ramayana" mention Gautam Buddha as thief, who was born in 563 BC, how come Ramayana written 1.6 millions years ago??

Comment: This is misinterpreted translation. See [Did Rama really call Buddha as a thief?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/18202/3500)

Comment: Bhim boy?? ha ha