# What is the mystery of ayOnija (अयोनिज) births?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, sita, draupadi

We will come across Sita in Valmiki Ramayana, as ayOnija - अयोनिज, a non-uterine birth.  Similarly, in Mahabharata, we read about Draupadi and Dhristadyumna, who are also ayOnijas, borne out of fire.

Human body consists of 5 elements, i.e., panchabhUta. After their birth, ayOnijas are also susceptible to human feelings and problems.

My questions are;

1. What is that technology or mantra sastra available in ancient India, which allows such things, which are *not natural*, to happen?
2. If they are ayOnijas, they cannot have prArabdha (stored karma) to reap.  Then why did they face problems?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55072/discussion-on-question-by-srimannarayana-k-v-what-is-the-mystery-of-ayonija-birt).

Comment: 'If they are ayOnijas, they cannot have prArabdha (stored karma) to reap.': Could you explain the reasoning behind this, or a link about it? It's an interesting thought.

Comment: Earth is karma Bhoomi...no one can live on earth without Karma's. That's y even god comes with karma and suffers...be it lord Rama or Krishna... everyone came to planet with some duties, to fulfill wishes of their devotees from previous life times...all these are Karma's or bandhan I can say

Comment: Body is only Ayonija i.e; took birth not naturally....the soul that lives in that body has performed karma in the previous birth i.e; it is natural and ordinary like other souls..so that soul came to earth and suffers too.

Comment: In previous Yugas no intercourse needed to beget a child. Only Yogabala is enough.

Comment: What's the significance of capital O in the question? Isn't Ayonija opposite of Yonija? If so, how they are splitted at O?

Comment: Capital "O"  in ayOnija, indicates long vowel at that point :-).  @YDS

Comment: ohh, i thought u wrote in some Camel/Pascale style...if you are showing long vowel then, a is supposed to be in caps, right? i noticed caps a and i but not o earlier, which transliteration r you following..?

Comment: "ayonija" births in scripture are metaphors.  Asking the faithful to believe them literally only weakens the cause of Hinduism.  Maybe they will become reality one day with cloning and other modern technologies.

Answer (score -2):

### Re: Draupadī and Dhṛṣṭadyumna

> *Similarly, in Mahabharata, we read about Draupadi and Dhristadyumna, who are also ayOnijas, borne out of fire.*

That's what the Mahābhārata initially tells us. In fact, we are told that a *youth* and a *young maiden* arose from the fire altar. Unlike Sītā's case, these are not babies. Most likely they were teenagers.

> Ādi Parva - Ch. 155
>
> Then a **youth** [Dhṛṣṭadyumna] who resembled a god arose from the flames. His
>   complexion was like the fire and his form was terrible. He wore a
>   crown on his head and his body was encased in excellent
>   armour. He had a sword in his hand and a bow and arrows and
>   he let out many loud roars. As soon as he was born, he ascended
>   a supreme chariot and went forth...
>
> Then a **young maiden** [Draupadī] arose from the centre of the altar. She was blessed with good fortune and was known as Panchali. She was beautiful and
>   her waist was shaped like an altar. She was dark. Her eyes were
>   like the petals of lotuses. Her hair was dark blue and curled. She
>   was truly a goddess born in human form. The sweet fragrance of
>   blue lotuses emanated from her body, a full 2 miles away. Her
>   form and supreme beauty were such that she had no equal on
>   earth. When the one with beautiful hips was born, the invisible
>   voice said,
>
> > Supreme among women, this beauty of the dark
> >     complexion will bring about the destruction of the Kshatriyas. In
> >     time, this one with the beautiful waist will perform the objective
> >     of the gods. From her will arise terrible fear among the
> >     Kshatriyas.
>
> *[Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 1 (pp. 401-402)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XY9RRPK)*

However, we are also told later that Draupadī had a very normal childhood with Dhṛṣṭadyumna and her other brothers:

> Vana Parva - Ch. 33
>
> Droupadi said,
>
> > O Partha! I have not insulted or censured
> >     dharma in any way. Why should I censure the supreme god, the
> >     lord of all beings? O descendant of the Bharata lineage! Know
> >     me as one who is incoherent with grief. Listen to me with a calm
> >     mind, as I lament a lot more. O destroyer of enemies! Whatever
> >     is born must certainly perform tasks. Not even inferior ones, but
> >     only the immobile can live without acting. O Yudhishthira!
> >     From the time one suckles at a breast to the time one is supine
> >     before death, all mobile beings act according to their nature.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > O Yudhishthira! He should wish for his misery and destruction. This is true of oceans and mountains, not to speak of mortal men. By looking for the weaknesses in an enemy, a man satisfies a debt to himself, as well as to the enemy. A man should never think ill of himself. O descendant of the Bharata lineage! Prosperity does not come to one who thinks of himself as having become overpowered.
> >
> > O descendant of the Bharata lineage! This is the foundation for the success of the world. It is said that the reasons for success are many and depend on the time and the place.
> >
> > In earlier times, a learned brahmana was lodged in my
> >     father's house. O bull among the Bharata lineage! He told all
> >     this, first propounded by Brihaspati, to my father. **He also
> >     taught all this to my brothers. I overheard this conversation at
> >     home.** O King Yudhishthira! He explained this to me
> >     comfortingly, when I would arrive on some task, or **when I was
> >     serving, or when I was seated on my father's lap**.
>
> *[Debroy, Bibek. The Mahabharata: Volume 2 (pp. 360-364)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XYN5YDK)*

If Draupadī and Dhṛṣṭadyumna were already teenagers when Drupada first found them, how was Draupadī able to give the above discourse on dharma to Yudhiṣṭhira? Where was the time to learn all the intricacies of dharma from her father and the brāhmaṇa guru?

Also, earlier in Ādi-parva (Ch. 155), when Draupadī and Dhṛṣṭadyumna rise up from the fire, Drupada's wife Pṛṣatī makes a special request:

> On seeing these two, Prishati wished to get them and came to Yaja and said,
>
> > **Let these two know no one but me as their mother**.
>
> Desiring to please the king, Yaja agreed. The Brahmanas, whose desires were entirely satisfied, gave the two names.
>
> > Because of his great courage and because he has been born from lustre, let this son of Drupada be called Dhrishtadyumna. Because she is dark in complexion, let her be called Krishna.

Drupada doesn't make the same request. This suggests Drupada could have fathered the two children from another woman and now Pṛṣatī is requesting the priests for a formal adoption.

So, instead of speculating on *the technology of miraculous births* of those times, you should be asking:

- **Why did Drupada cover up the fact that he had children with his legal wife Pṛṣatī or another woman until they were teenagers?**
- **And what was the need to conduct a yajña to introduce them to the whole world?**

Comment: Thanks for attempting.  You are trying to provide answer from practical angle. I think there is another angle.   Why can't we assume that the technology in that era had reached highest level and  think in cloning angle? @sv.

Comment: "think in cloning angle" - that's scientific speculation and [not suited](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121/political-and-scientific-questions-are-off-topic-for-hinduism-se) for this site. Your other question ([Did Ramayana occur 1.6 million years ago?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9009/did-ramayana-occur-1-6-million-years-ago)) is also trying to link modern science with Hindu scripture ("Modern anthropologists say that elephants with four tusks existed 12-1.6 million years ago"). This is again scientific speculation and not allowed.

Comment: _Why can't we assume that the technology in that era had reached highest level_ - this is wishful thinking at best. The [oldest human fossil](https://www.sciencemag.org/news/2017/06/world-s-oldest-homo-sapiens-fossils-found-morocco) is from 300,000 years ago and they must used primitive stone tools. They struggled for food and survival. How do you expect them to be cloning themselves using stone tools? @srimannarayanakv

Comment: It is your way of thinking.  I have different ideas :-)@sv.

Comment: Coming to the aspect of scientific speculation,  you have to remember that I had kept the options open in my question.   I made comment of cloning only in here. :-) @sv.

Comment: In respect of Sita you have not commented in your answer please @sv.

Comment: "What is that technology or mantra sastra available in ancient India, which allows such things...not natural, to happen?" - this is like asking, 'how can mantras bring rain?' What is the technology behind it? This would naturally lead to scientific speculation. I have to cite a scientific paper to properly answer the question. But citing scientific research is not allowed here because this is a site for religion and no one can validate my scientific claims. So you are only allowed to ask questions like: Do mantras bring rain? If Sita & Draupadi are ayonijas, how does karma work for them?

Comment: Re: Sita, I have a similar answer which I will add/update later, but if you are hoping for a 'human cloning' type of answer, Quora might be a better place. @srimannarayanakv

Comment: Question about mantra sastra is banned in HSE? When was it banned?  This question was asked nearly 4 years back. You can decide for yourself. By suggesting to Quora are you suggesting me to move out from here?.@sv.

Comment: 'Question about mantra sastra is banned in HSE?' - if framed properly they are allowed. E.g., there was a question about about Brahmastra recently. But it only asked how to launch it based on Hindu scripture. 'By suggesting to Quora are you suggesting me to move out from here?' - no, only this question. I see lot of speculative answers on Quora with no references. But this site has higher standards for both questions and answers. @srimannarayanakv