# Secret behind great personalities' birth stories from Ramayana and Mahabharata? Are there any signs of them in Kaliyuga?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, birth

In Ramayana and Mahabharata few well known characters are not born from Womb. Most of all unusual births. Few Examples Here: Lord Rama and his 3 brothers  (born after eating Dessert) Karna and Pandavas (Mantra), Kauravas (Lump of Flesh)  and Drona (Born in a Vessel), Is it true. If yes, How is it possible?

Does it happen only once in period of Ramayana and Mahabharata, are there are any signs in Kaliyuga?

Comment: Yogavatar of Shiva, Lakulin, was born  when Shiva entered into dead body in this Kali Yuga. But we really don't know whether really [Lakulisha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakulisha) was born like that.

Comment: Most famous case would be Jesus is said to be of virgin birth. I believe it, even though it's not traditional Hindu mythology, because the word 'Jesus' comes from 'Yeshu' which is from 'Isha', which is sanskrit word (Ishvar), and anyone with that level of spirituality will have roots in sanatana dharma.

Comment: Where did you get the idea that Lord Rama and his three brothers are not born from womb? They are born from womb after their mother eat dessert.

Comment: @TriyugiNarayanMani Yeah, that's why I mention few well knows personality. My main intention was secret behind birth.

Comment: There's already a question on this topic: [What is the mystery of ayOnija births?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/9204/2995)

Comment: @sv. it might be partially same topic, but both are unanswered.

Comment: @pandya, How can you make it Duplicate without having evidence. If you think yes please provide me the proof.

Comment: @CR241 You asked: "few well known characters are not born from womb...How is it possible?" Other question asks the exact same thing. So I think they're duplicates. You can edit your question to make it unique and different from the other. Then ask to be reopened.

Comment: @sv. I can change Title but I don't want to change my question. If I edit my question also you think it's same. So Forget about thinking to make duplicates, try to find answer.

Comment: @CR241 It appears you're talking closing your question personally. The other question not having an answer doesn't mean we can 10 similar sounding questions open until one of them gets answered. Anyway, I'm working on answer to 'What is the mystery of ayOnija births?' - after I write the answer will leave a comment here.

Comment: @sv. Good luck Sir..! I didn't take anything personal and never mind where you are going to answer. But my concern is how previous and my question are related, don't say main content was same. while leaving comment here if you can try to find answer for "Karna and Pandavas (Mantra), Kauravas (Lump of Flesh) and Dhrona (Born in a Vessel), Is it true. If yes, How they are born not from Womb?"

Comment: @CR241 You can join the chat room: [Rational Thinkers](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52488/rational-thinkers) to discuss more on 'Kauravas (Lump of Flesh)' - I started that chat room thinking of that exact thing :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60035/discussion-between-cr241-and-sv).

Comment: Saint Kabir's birth is not known. Goda Devi's birth is not known. It seems in Kali yuga, while we are not witness actual  rising out of fire etc., advanced souls manifest themselves magically.

Comment: where are you @sv. ? you claim my question was duplicate of https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/9204/what-is-the-mystery-of-ayonija-births and you told me that you are going to answer this question. You guys made false statement and make my question duplicate. I don't care what ever but where is the answer.