# Should Uttar kand be considered an interpolation to Valmiki Ramayan or not?

Tags: ramayana, rama, valmiki

I don't know Sanskrit so read english translation of Valmiki Ramayan. The way Yuddha Kand ends make it seem like epic ends here only, yet another kand exists.

Comment: Does this answer your question https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/20933/26679

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is the Uttara Kanda of the Srimad Valmiki Ramayana interpolated?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20933/is-the-uttara-kanda-of-the-srimad-valmiki-ramayana-interpolated)